# Intro to Java Error: cannot find symbol - Class ArrayList

Tags: java

this is my first time taking a programming language. Why is BlueJ giving me an error for both ArrayList? I want to test my inputs so that if they are in the arraylist it will return true, otherwise it will return false? Step 2 of this will be using a for loop.

```
private boolean isValidProvince(String province)
   {

    ArrayList<String> provinceList;
    provinceList = new ArrayList<String>(10);
    provinceList.add("British Columbia");
    provinceList.add("Alberta");
    provinceList.add("Saskatchewan");
    provinceList.add("Manitoba");
    provinceList.add("Ontario");
    provinceList.add("Quebec");
    provinceList.add("Newfoundland");
    provinceList.add("Prince Edward Island");
    provinceList.add("Nova Scotia");
    provinceList.add("New Brunswick"); 

    if(province.equals(province)){
                return true;
    }else{
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably your code is missing the required import statement. We can't say without a [mcve].

Comment: You'll need a line like `import java.util.ArrayList;` right at the top of your code.

Comment: And comparing if province is equal to itself does not look correct btw... You want to use provinceList.contains() instead.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Arrays, you have to [import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) the library correctly (at the top of the source code, outside the class). Also if you want to compare if the province string is on the list, you could use [contains method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)), like this:

### TestA Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList; // <- import!

public class TestA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isValidProvince("Alberta"));
        System.out.println(isValidProvince("Asd"));
        System.out.println(isValidProvince("TEst"));
        System.out.println(isValidProvince("British Columbia"));
    }

    private static boolean isValidProvince(String province) {

        ArrayList<String> provinceList;
        provinceList = new ArrayList<String>(10);
        provinceList.add("British Columbia");
        provinceList.add("Alberta");
        provinceList.add("Saskatchewan");
        provinceList.add("Manitoba");
        provinceList.add("Ontario");
        provinceList.add("Quebec");
        provinceList.add("Newfoundland");
        provinceList.add("Prince Edward Island");
        provinceList.add("Nova Scotia");
        provinceList.add("New Brunswick");

        return provinceList.contains(province); //will return true if contains province, false otherwise (this way you avoid if block
    }

}
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: simply `return provinceList.contains(province);`

Comment: That's correct. I'll edit my answer. thanks!

Comment: In order to use *ArrayList,* you need to import the *class* correctly.

Comment: Indeed @EJP. It is imported in the answer